# How to ensure ordering of multiple parameters when using Dapper + ODBC/MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, parameters, odbc, dapper

Normally Dapper queries allow me to do something like this:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_value = @MyParameter";
var parameter = new {MyParameter = 20};
connection.Query(query,parameter);
```

or like this

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_value = @MyParameter";
var parameter = new DynamicParameters();
parameter.Add("@MyParameter",20);
connection.Query(query,parameter);
```

This doesn't work with an `OdbcConnection` because named parameters are not supported. Instead a "?" can be used to mark parameters:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_value = ?";
var parameter = new {MyParameter = 20};
connection.Query(query,parameter);
```

or

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_value = ?";
var parameter = new DynamicParameters();
parameter.Add("@MyParameter",20);
connection.Query(query,parameter);
```

This works fine for single parameter, but I cannot find any source telling me what happens with multiple parameters. I've tested the following:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE  some_value > ? AND some_value < ?";
var parameter = new {Min= 20, Max =30};
connection.Query(query,parameter);
```

or

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_value > ? AND some_value < ?"
var parameter = new DynamicParameters();
parameter.Add("Min",20);
parameter.Add("Max",30);
connection.Query(query,parameter);
```

And it works just fine, but I'd like to be certain that the order in which I create anonymous object properties or the order in which I add parameters to the `DynamicParameter` is guaranteed to be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment by Amit Joshi I found that "pseudo positional parameters" can be used

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_value > ?MinValue? AND some_value < ?MaxValue?"
```

the order of parameters added to DynamicParameters or an anonymous object then no longer matter.